# ID autoincrement adds '0' as entry if try to add with empty field . PhPAdmin,Xammp,pymysql,tkinter,python

Tags: tkinter, xampp, pymysql

```
    self.ID_var=IntVar()
    self.Year_var = StringVar()
    self.name_var = StringVar()
    self.course_var=StringVar()
    self.email_var = StringVar()
    self.gender_var = StringVar()
    self.category_var=StringVar()
    self.contact_var = StringVar()
    self.dob_var = StringVar()
    self.search_by = StringVar()
    self.search_txt = StringVar()
    self.Student_table = ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame,columns=("ID","Year","Name","Course","Email","Gender","Category","Contact","DOB","Address"),xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set,yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
    self.Student_table.heading("ID",text="ID")
    self.Student_table.heading("Year",text="Year")
    self.Student_table.heading("Name", text="Name")
    self.Student_table.heading("Course", text="Course")
    self.Student_table.heading("Email", text="Email")
    self.Student_table.heading("Gender", text="Gender")
    self.Student_table.heading("Category", text="Category")
    self.Student_table.heading("Contact", text="Contact")
    self.Student_table.heading("DOB", text="DOB")
    self.Student_table.heading("Address", text="Address")
    self.Student_table['show'] = "headings"
    self.Student_table.column("ID",width=80,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Year",width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Name", width=160)
    self.Student_table.column("Course", width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Email", width=180,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Gender", width=80,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Category", width=80,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Contact", width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("DOB", width=100,anchor=CENTER)
    self.Student_table.column("Address", width=260)
    self.Student_table.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    self.Student_table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.get_cursor)
    self.fetch_data()
    self.clear()
def fetch_data(self):
    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="project")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from std")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows)!=0:
            
            self.Student_table.delete(*self.Student_table.get_children())

            for row in rows:
                self.Student_table.insert('',END,values=row)
    con.commit()
    self.clear()

    con.close()
def clear(self):
    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="project")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from std where ID=%s",self.ID_var.get())
    
    self.ID_var.set("0")
    self.Year_var.set("")
    self.name_var.set("")
    self.course_var.set("")
    self.email_var.set("")
    self.gender_var.set("")
    self.category_var.set("")
    self.contact_var.set("")
    self.dob_var.set("")
    self.txt_Address.delete("1.0",END)
def get_cursor(self,ev):
    cursor_row = self.Student_table.focus()
    contents = self.Student_table.item(cursor_row)
    row = contents['values']
    self.ID_var.set(row[0])
    self.Year_var.set(row[1])
    self.name_var.set(row[2])
    self.course_var.set(row[3])
    self.email_var.set(row[4])
    self.gender_var.set(row[5])
    self.category_var.set(row[6])
    self.contact_var.set(row[7])
    self.dob_var.set(row[8])
    self.txt_Address.delete("1.0", END)
    self.txt_Address.insert(END, row[9])
def add_student(self):
    if(self.ID_var=="" or self.ID_var=="0" or self.Year_var=="" or self.name_var=="" or self.course_var=="" or self.email_var=="" or self.gender_var=="" or self.category_var=="" or self.contact_var=="" or self.dob_var=="" or self.txt_Address==""):
        messagebox.showerror("Error","All fields are compulsory")
    else:
        con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="project")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into std values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(self.ID_var.get(),self.Year_var.get(),self.name_var.get()
        ,self.course_var.get(),self.email_var.get(),self.gender_var.get(),self.category_var.get(),self.contact_var.get(),self.dob_var.get(),self.txt_Address.get('1.0',END)))
        con.commit()
    
        self.fetch_data()
        
        self.clear()
        con.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Success","Record has been added successfully")
```

*Hi,
I am new to coding. I have set ID as INT auto-increment in sql. Problem is when I give nothing to entry field then press 'Add' button it enters 0 as ID value to the table. I have used ID as IntVar, and used a condition for the error message to perform when user tries to add empty fields. But its not working. How can I resolve it?